# Glassfish EJB server + OpenEJB client

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, openejb

Is it possible not to use Java EE Application client from Glassfish to access EJB on Server. I would like to try using OpenEJB for a standalone Java SE client. Is it possible? I cannot find anything in the Internet on the topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.  The OpenEJB client only works with EJBs running in an OpenEJB container. There is support for running the container in Tomcat, Geronimo as well as standalone or embedded in a plain Java SE app, but there is no support for running it in GlassFish.

Side note that OpenEJB does support reading and using the GlassFish deployment descriptors, so if you were tempted to try running your EJBs in an environment where OpenEJB is the container, it should be fairly easy.